# How to right align a flipswitch in jquery mobile 1.4.5

Tags: html, css, cordova, jquery-mobile, jquery-mobile-flipswitch

I'm trying to create a "Preference" page for a mobile App created with JQM and PhoneGap.

The flipswitch appears right in front of the text, but not aligned to the right (as native preferences/settings usually appear), so it looks very disorganized.

These two other posts are similar:
[How do you make a flipswitch on the right corner of a fixed header in jQuery Mobile?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25009376/how-do-you-make-a-flipswitch-on-the-right-corner-of-a-fixed-header-in-jquery-mob)
[How to right-align a flip toggle switch in jQuery mobile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7313360/how-to-right-align-a-flip-toggle-switch-in-jquery-mobile)

But neither solv my problem properly (in the first link it looks awful and in the second, well, it's not flipswitch element)

An example of my code:

http://jsfiddle.net/JTGE6/23/

HTML

```
<label for="radiog_lite_Selec" class="lablsett">Selec</label>
<select name="radiog_lite_Selec" data-mini="true" id="radiog_lite_Selec" data-role="flipswitch" style="position: absolute; right: 0;">
    <option value="1">On</option>
    <option value="0">Off</option>
</select>
```

css

```
.ui-mobile label.lablsett
{
    left: 0 !important;
    float: left;
    margin-right: 10px;
    margin-left: 10px;
    margin-top: 10px;
    color: #000;
}
```

**My question: How can the Label Text to the left and the flipswith (in front of the text) but aligned to the right?**

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put each option row in a container div:

```
<div class="optContainer">
    <label for="radiog_lite_Selec" class="lablsett">Select</label>
    <select name="radiog_lite_Selec" data-mini="true" id="radiog_lite_Selec" data-role="flipswitch" style="position: absolute; right: 0;">    
        <option value="1">On</option>    
        <option value="0">Off</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

Then use CSS to float the flipswitch div to the right:

```
.ui-mobile label.lablsett {
    left: 0 !important;
    float: left;
    margin-right: 10px;
    margin-left: 10px;
    margin-top: 10px;
    color: #000;
}
.optContainer .ui-flipswitch {
    float: right;
    margin-right: 10px;
}
```

> Updated **[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/JTGE6/25/)**

Comment: Hi ezanker! Thank you for the answer, this is perfect!